# SUMPRODUCT Formula using Date and Values - Won't work when I move to another Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm having issues with a formula, it works fine on the sheet that has the data as I'm using it to calculate figures based on a sales by month basis

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(G:G)=3)*(YEAR(G:G)=2017)*(M:M))
```

there is too much info on the sheet i'm using so want to move this formula to another sheet in the same work book, but when I add the usual reference sheet formula it doesn't work.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('Stock'!G:G)=3)*(YEAR('Stock'!G:G)=2017)*('Stock'!M:M))
```

Can Anyone Help - I'm Intermediate in Excel and bundled through just to get this far

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`?

Comment: It should work. I just mocked it up and it works here. Is it possible that you've disabled calculation on `another sheet`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula: Just mocked up yours.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Stock!G:G)=3)*(YEAR(Stock!G:G)=2017)*(Stock!M:M))
```